# Feature class is not imported in ArcSDE in ArcCatalog

Tags: arcgis-desktop, enterprise-geodatabase, import, arccatalog

I installed ArcEditor and ArcSDE. In my computer ArcEditor 9.3.1, ArcGIS Server 9.3.1, ArcSDE 9.3.1 and Oracle 11g are installed. I did all things by the Guide of ESRI: ArcGIS Server, Configuration and setting for Oracle. All the procedures passed normally.

But when I import feature class in ArcSDE in ArcCatalog, the process starts but does not end. I tried to copy the class. Window of primary parameters opens. After clicking OK a window of copying opens. But it is blank and hangs.

Comment: It's important to understand that data does not exist "in" ArcSDE. It lives *in* the database, and is accessed *with* the ArcSDE API. So details about which database is in use, along with which version of ArcGIS, and which version of the Enterprise geodatabase is installed in that database are critical pieces of any EGDB question.

Comment: 9.3.1 was released over eleven years ago. It was retired nearly six and a half years ago. There were hundreds of potential issues back when this was supported, and thousands now. I'm afraid GIS SE is not the solution to your problem.